# my function returns null results and I'm not sure what is wrong (MySQL)

Tags: sql

My function to find the cheapest property with n bedrooms is always returning null. I'm not sure what the issue is right now.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cheapest_property_with_n_bedrooms;
CREATE FUNCTION cheapest_property_with_n_bedrooms (numBedrooms INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE PropertyID INT;
        DECLARE bedrooms INT;
        SET PropertyID = (SELECT Property.property_id
                            FROM Property
                            JOIN Listing ON Listing.property_FK = Property.property_id
                            JOIN Amenities ON Amenities.property_FK = Property.property_id
                            GROUP BY Amenities.num_bedrooms
                            HAVING Amenities.num_bedrooms = numBedrooms 
                            );
        RETURN PropertyID;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Amenities (
    amenities_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    property_FK INT,
    num_bedrooms INT,
    num_bathrooms INT,
    num_garage INT,
    num_kitchen INT,
    num_parking INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_AMENITIES_PROPERTY FOREIGN KEY (property_FK) REFERENCES Property(property_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Property (
    property_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    property_name VARCHAR(50),
    address_FK INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PROPERTY_ADDRESS FOREIGN KEY (address_FK) REFERENCES Address(address_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```

My query to call the function is this, where you can replace it with any number of bedrooms desired.

SELECT cheapest_property_with_n_bedrooms (1);

Comment: What is the purpose of the `GROUP BY Amenities.num_bedrooms` clause?

Comment: If i dont have that line, i get an error when i run the function that says:  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Amenities.num_bedrooms' in 'having clause'

Comment: It would probably be useful if you tag your specific RDBMS - I'm assuming it's MySql.  I'm more of a SQL Server guy, but either way I'm pretty sure your PropertyID variable is likely not being set because the query you've assigned to it is probably returning multiple rows.  You could try at least changing it to ... (SELECT TOP 1 Property.property_id ..., but you'll probably also need to add an ORDER BY to the query, to set the criteria on which particular property should be returned if there happen to be multiple candidates

Comment: Thanks, I will remember to do that from now on. It slipped my mind because I just starting learning SQL and forgot about the differences between the management systems!